# Firefox import assertions not currently supported

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, es6-modules

Firefox throws and unsupported error on:

`import sheet from '/Vanilla/ScrollGrid.css' assert {type: 'css'};`

[Can I use](https://caniuse.com/?search=import%20assert) says Unsupported.

and "Missing )" error after:

`myCSSMod = await import(userStyles, { assert: {type: "css"} })`

[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=assert()) says ok.

If I remove all asserts the IMPORT css statement throws: -

Loading module from “http://localhost/Vanilla/ScrollGrid.css” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/css”).

Is there a feature detection work around for FireFox?

Comment: Maybe you can find a solution [here.](https://superuser.com/questions/1787865/disable-content-type-detection-for-css-types-in-firefox)

Comment: FWIW: The `assert` keyword is deprecated in favor of `with`. See the feature [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-attributes) for details. AFAIK, only JSON and JavaScript modules are supported at this time — no implementation has ever supported importing CSS resources, but it is a subject of ongoing discussion.

Comment: Chrome supports both beautifully and the spec says "assert" with be supported for the foreseeable future. Edge and Firefox fail. Anyone n=know about Safari?

Comment: Google is known for throwing technologies against the wall to see what sticks. Weird it is not supported in Edge, it is Chromium.

Comment: @danny Soorry it does work on Edge. Surprisingly, I had left off a "/" on a relative url to a new module and the error I got on bothe Edge and Chrome was about unexpexted mime type text/Css in my style sheet import.